# I am unable to add new data to the MySQL database using Nodejs and Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, api, express

I am trying to create a REST Api using nodejs , express and mySQL. Select and Delete function for MySQL through node js are working perfectly, the api is able to fetch and delete data using Node.js  but the insert query is not working.

```
app.post('/add', function(req, res){

    let result;
    let query = `insert into student (id, name, age, address, dob) 
                values(${req.body.id}, '${req.body.name}','${req.body.age}','${req.body.address}', '${req.body.dob}')
                on duplicate key update
                age = '${req.body.age}',
                name = '${req.body.name}',
                address = '${req.body.address}',
                dob = '${req.body.dob} ' `
    connection.query(query, {
         age : req.body.age ,
                name :req.body.name,
                address :req.body.address ,
                dob : req.body.dob ,
          id: req.body.id

    }
        , function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log(results.insertid);
        result = results;
      });

      res.json(result);
});
```

The add function should be able to post data to the MYSQL database through Nodejs.
It is showing this error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) .

Comment: So what's the exact error message you get?

Comment: there is a fault of routing i think. print something in second line and check in console. maybe you used a wrong path